# Can we change the duplicate accepting message?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I just asked a question on meta and despite my effort to find an existing question, got a justified closing vote.

But my question is: can we change the message on the message box? While my question is the complete duplicate (alas), I don't agree with the message that says "That solved my problem!".

The original question didn't get solved, so how is mine supposed to be solved?

Would it be more appropriate to put on a more general label, something like "Yes, that is the same question!" or "I agree, that is a duplicate!"?

[image]

Comment: The definition of dupe is not _"it's the same question as the dupe target"_, but _"answers in the dupe target answer this question"_. So saying _"it is the same question"_ is plain wrong. Saying _"it is a duplicate"_ is wrong because it does nothing to explain _what_ a duplicate entails. So either of those wording would be more problematic than what we have now, IMO.

Comment: The definition is skewed on meta, since it's possible to close questions as dupes of questions without answers. Not so in main.

Comment: @yivi, you are saying that accepting "that solved my problem" would be correct? Even though I disagree with it but accept the duplicate? No sense

Comment: I'm saying that the existing message is better than what you propose for the vast majority of cases. On meta, where a question can be closed as a dupe of a question without answers, it can sometimes be somewhat imprecise. I'm not sure it's worth adding logic to check for this scenario and display a different message.

Comment: While I understand the idea, the proposed solution is not great. It's already hard to make people accept what a dupe is. With word like the "the same question" , I expect people arguing why their question is different because the variable name is not capitalised. But meta is different, for different kind of people. Eg, Take Post Ban rant question, they are identify as duplicate only by their smell. But all rant post are totaly different with an incredible creativity. And the Answer of the dupe target will never "Solve their problem!".

Comment: I don't insist on the new message content to be absolutely as I wrote above, just the fact that as it is it is misleading and should be more generic

Comment: @yivi just fyi, in the main site a question can be closed as dupe of a question with no answers. That happens, for instance, if OP asks the same thing again (I myself have closed those several times). Obviously that's not what this OP is talking about here.

Comment: Regarding the main site (not meta), OP's idea makes sense in some situations. I have no idea of how often it happens, but suppose this scenario: Someone asks a question, which is closed as a duplicate of an existing one. Let's suppose that both questions are exactly the same, ipsis litteris, just for the sake of the argument. The dupe target has answers, and even upvoted ones. However, those answers didn't fix their OP's issue (and that original OP remained silent for whatever reason). Therefore, those answers also don't fix the issue of this new OP, whose question was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado If _"those answers also don't fix the issue of this new OP"_, then the new OP's problem isn't solved, and clicking `That solved my problem` would be plain wrong. They can edit their question to explain how the existing solutions don't solve the new problem.

Comment: @MrLister But that precisely my point. Suppose there is nothing to edit, the question is a clear cut case and all the relevant info is there, but it has been asked before (therefore, its clearly a dupe) and the original answers don't fix neither the original question nor the dupe. That's is the case where *"That solved my problem!"* don't fit, but *"No, my question is different"* neither! In my hypothetical scenario above the question is not different.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado In that case, I'd propose changing the text of the "_No, my question is different_" remark rather than the caption on the button.

Comment: Not sure if it solves the issue you're talking about here, but with the rollout of the new post notices, the notice has been changed to "Does this answer your question? [Submit]"